# Creating New Tabs Based on a List of Names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet which has a 'Class List' and 'Template' sheet. Once names are added to the 'Class List' (C5:C) I would like to generate a new tab for each name based on the 'Template' sheet. The names of these new tabs will reflect the names in the list. The class list will be constantly changing and being added to.

This is the code I am currently using and it works perfectly, however, it always generates 1x blank, un-named tab at the end (See picture below). Is there a way to stop this from happening?

[image]

```
function newSheet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Class List")
    var getNames = sheet1.getRange("C5:C").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
    var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
    if (copy) {
        Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
    } else {
        templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
        ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
        ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, no un-named sheet is created in my test spreadsheet. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information) in order to reproduce this behaviour? Most probably you have cells with blank spaces (but not empty cells), so they're not getting filtered out.

Comment: Thank you - I just tried clearing the cells and trying again - I still had the same issue of it generating the un-named tab. Here is a copy of the file I'm trying to edit:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/160qqDp_VIvyANMwpsuwfUVYoqPVQTiVve3P8x5L4FMY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't clear the cells. At least not in the spreadsheet you shared. I posted an answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Many cells in your column C look empty but in fact contain whitespaces (`" "`), so these cell values are not getting filtered out by doing `.filter(String)`. Because of this, a sheet named `" "` is created.

#### Solution:

Use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove whitespaces. For example, you could do this:

```
getNames = getNames.filter(value => value.trim() !== "");
```

#### Note:

I'm not sure why you are using [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) and [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). If your purpose is to transform the 2D array to a simple array (that is, an array in which each element is a string, not another array) you could use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) instead.

You could do something like this instead:

```
var getNames = sheet1.getRange("C5:C").getValues().flat().filter(value => {
  return value.trim() !== ""
})
```